# only 1 tile visible in GE after gdal_translate -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY

Tags: gdal, kml

I have a 3-band ASTER scene in any of several formats (PCIDISK, GeoTIFF, Imagine), already reprojected to the geographic coordinate system. I can view and manipulate the scene successfully in PCI Geomatica and ESRI ArcMap. I want to create a KMZ version of it, and following in part this other [GIS StackExchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/batch-convert-geotiffs-to-kmz-files), I tried using:

```
gdal_translate -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY myscene.tif myscene.kmz
```

but the result is invisible in Google Earth (although it zooms to the correct area). It remains invisible when zooming way out and way in, except that the lower-left tile of the 16 tiles it created **does** show up when zooming in. It, however, is completely black as it is in the no-data collar around the image data.

Also, if I unzip the KMZ and open any of the individual tile KMLs that were created, **they** open just fine, and the ones that are not in the collar show the correct image data. So I suspect there's something wrong in the way the output KMZ was formed (which uses Regions and NetworkLinks, KML elements I have not worked with before). But I don't know whether this is due to input data or format problems, to incorrect or missing parameters to gdal_translate, or something else. I've tried several input formats with the same results each time.

Tips and suggestions (if not outright answers!) much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug in GDAL 1.9.0, and fixed in 1.9.1:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4527