# Loading USGS 1:24,000 quads into Garmin GPS-receiver — how to convert to a kmz Garmin understands?

Tags: cartography, pdf, garmin, usgs

I have downloaded USGS 1:24,000 topos (the classic one, not the useless US Topo) from the [USGS Map Locator & Downloader](http://store.usgs.gov/b2c_usgs/usgs/maplocator/(xcm=r3standardpitrex_prd&layout=6_1_61_48_1&uiarea=2&ctype=areaDetails&carea=%24ROOT)/.do).  How can I load those into my Garmin GPSmap?

Following advice at [this forum post](https://forums.gpsfiledepot.com/index.php?topic=3038.0), I converted a PDF to KMZ using:

```
gdal_translate -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY UT_Cannonville_248430_1966_24000_geo.{pdf,kmz} -co FORMAT=JPEG
```

The resulting kmz looks fine in Google Earth, so clearly the georeferencing information is present in the PDF.  But when I mount my GPSmap 62 and copy the kmz to the `Garmin/CustomMaps` directory (as instructed [here](https://forums.garmin.com/showthread.php?2646-Technical-Details) or [here](https://garminbasecamp.wikispaces.com/Maps?responseToken=3f115d39b8d36cdab4a1c7292c874951)), it does not show up on the device.  The problem may be related to [what is reported here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/batch-convert-geotiffs-to-kmz-files#comment245631_20936).  How do I convert the kmz to a format that Garmin understands?